# Como delimitar o número de caracteres escritos por linha em uma saída "txt", no R?

Tags: string, r, caracteres

Estou escrevendo um *filelog* e quero imprimi-lo em uma folha A4. Uma das partes deste *filelog* tem uma variável, com a seguinte estrutura:

```
cod<-c(82024,82042,82067,82098,82106,82113,82141,82145,82178,82181,82184,82188,82191,82198,82212,82240,82246,82263,82280,82287,82294,82296,82298,82317,82326,82331,82336,82353,82361,82376,82382,82392,82397,82410,82425,82445,82460,82474,82476,82480,82487,82493,82533,82562,82564,82571,82578,82583,82586,82588,82590,82594,82596,82598,82610,82659,82668,82676,82678,82683)
```

Como posso escrever o vetor `cod` em um arquivo .txt com até 80 caracteres por linha, considerando que os elementos sejam separados por espaço como segue o exemplo:

82487 82493 82533 82562 82564 82571 82578 82583 82586 82588 82590 82594 82596

Cada linha terá 13 elementos (5 caracteres + 1 espaço por elemento).

OBS: O limite de 80 defini em função da largura da folha.

Comment: Algumas dúvidas: Qual é o objetivo de se fazer isso? Como você quer separar os números?

Comment: Já vou editar a pergunta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você quer pode ser facilmente alcançado utilizando apenas a função `cat`. Por exemplo:

```
cat(cod, file = "jean.txt", fill = 80)
```

Vai criar o arquivo `jean.txt` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
82024 82042 82067 82098 82106 82113 82141 82145 82178 82181 82184 82188 82191 
82198 82212 82240 82246 82263 82280 82287 82294 82296 82298 82317 82326 82331 
82336 82353 82361 82376 82382 82392 82397 82410 82425 82445 82460 82474 82476 
82480 82487 82493 82533 82562 82564 82571 82578 82583 82586 82588 82590 82594 
82596 82598 82610 82659 82668 82676 82678 82683
```

O parâmetro `fill` limita o tamanho máximo da linha, quebrando entre os elementos de `cod`. Se quiser separar os elementos com outro caractere, pode utilizar `sep`. Se quiser um caractere inicial por linha (como ocorre quando se usa `print`), existe o argumento `labels`. Você também pode testar no console e usar `file` só quando for salvar mesmo. Por exemplo:

```
> cat(cod, fill = 80, labels = paste0("[", seq(1, 1000, by = 12), "]"), sep = ", ")
[1] 82024, 82042, 82067, 82098, 82106, 82113, 82141, 82145, 82178, 82181, 
[13] 82184, 82188, 82191, 82198, 82212, 82240, 82246, 82263, 82280, 82287, 
[25] 82294, 82296, 82298, 82317, 82326, 82331, 82336, 82353, 82361, 82376, 
[37] 82382, 82392, 82397, 82410, 82425, 82445, 82460, 82474, 82476, 82480, 
[49] 82487, 82493, 82533, 82562, 82564, 82571, 82578, 82583, 82586, 82588, 
[61] 82590, 82594, 82596, 82598, 82610, 82659, 82668, 82676, 82678, 82683
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou!